# Upload file to a folder on other asp.net mvc website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two asp.net MVC websites. One the front end(mysite.com) and one the backend(admin.mysite.com).

They both use the same database and everything is working fine. But, I am facing the issue in upload. I want to upload images in front end **content** folder from the admin website. How can that be achieved?

Using `Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Products/product")` locates the folder in admin website.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the iis server, you could set up a virtual directory that is pointed at the desired folder on your front end site.

All that would be required from the front end is that you point the upload path to the virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath("~/Files")` returns an absolute path based on a folder relative to your application. The leading ~/ tells ASP.Net to look at the root of your application.

To use a folder outside of the application you can use the full path:
`@"E:\Project\Folders\Content\Images\Products\product"`

You can also get the full path directory:

`string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`

Comment: I am using a shared hosting service. So don't know the full path. How can that be known

Comment: To get the full path use  string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: k. will give this a shot

Comment: getting 500 error. tried `string renamedImage = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Products/product" + pictureCount + extension);
                renamedImage = renamedImage.Replace("admin.mysite.com", "mysite.com");
                upload.SaveAs(renamedImage);`